# Ubuntu alongside windows

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am having ALOT of trouble trying to install ubuntu 12.04 along side windows 7 home. When I use either the live disk or flash drive and get to the point where it gives me a choice to install it says i already have multiple operating systems installed and does not give me the option to install along side windows 7. This issue has kept me up for 2 nights can anyone shed some light on how I could fix this problem.

Comment: I have sympathy for you, but this is probably better asked on <http://askubuntu.com>. Tip: you might want to check if any of the systems is a recovery OS. Or a half-finished Ubuntu install. Or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for reply i have no half-finished ubuntu however I do have Recovery(D:) and HP_TOOLS(E:) could this be confusing ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think so, to be honest. But I've already flagged your question for transfer. Hope you get more assistance there. You should provide any more details you have, in any case.

Comment: Hmmm ubuntu says i have two win 7 boot loader could this be the problem?

Comment: When you look at the disk with gParted or some other disk partitioning tool how many Primary partitions are already there? There can only be 4 so if Windows is already occupying all four you will have to make some other changes before you can install Ubuntu. As @icedwater says though, you'll get better help at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Ive actually got more help here, i know ask ubuntu seems like the obvious place but no help at all.

Comment: I fixed my problem. I deleted and merged all partitions. This has fixed the problem I now have the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows 7.

The extra partitions I had were Recovery(D:) "not user about the letters HP_Tools(F:)

I hope this can help anyone who is/was having similar problem

Comment: If there is a problem with 12.04, I am sure Ubuntu 13.04 would probably not.